# android - Place imageview next to two textviews under each other

Tags: android, android-layout

[image]

How do i create above layout in android studio ?

Comment: Did you try something?

Comment: yes i tried using table layout within a linear layout but it did not work. i mean i did not get the desired output.

Comment: Ignore all the down-votes, I wish more people would use images to ask layout questions. 
As for "where is the code?" If you don't know then why post junk that doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First add  dependencies in your gradle file for [circular image view](https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView)

```
 compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
```

now you can use below code as per your requirement

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="3">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center">

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/meal_image_order"
            android:layout_width="96dp"
            android:layout_height="96dp"
            android:src="@color/colorAccent"
            app:civ_border_color="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            app:civ_border_width="2dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Textview 1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Textview 2" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

sample output

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First add line in your app level build.gradle file following line of code in dependencies

```
 compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
```

after try following code

```
   <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/meal_image_order"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:src="@mipmap/profile" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="2">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv1"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:gravity="start"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Broad Bean" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv2"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:gravity="start"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:text="Broad" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  [<RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/view"
                    android:gravity="fill_horizontal|center">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/dp"
                        android:layout_width="60dp"
                        android:layout_height="60dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/lea" />


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/s_name"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView"
                        android:layout_marginStart="85dp"
                        android:gravity="fill_vertical"
                        android:text="Mathan"
                        android:textColor="#78038A"
                        android:textSize="18.5dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/s_code"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/s_name"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/s_name"
                        android:fontFamily="serif"
                        android:gravity="fill_vertical"
                        android:text="4320 - XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="16dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                </RelativeLayout>][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yzg8V.jpg
```